# Android Layout Within Layout Design

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to make an app that has the same layout design as this (First picture on this page) http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/speech-input.html ..

I dont know how to Achieve this task ..

Thanks in Advance.. =)

Comment: What have you tried? Have you read through [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html) doc?

Comment: Are you familiar with android design basics?

Comment: @Kabuko Sir I know The Difference btw the layouts :) .. I have not read it thoroughly but i Know it..

Comment: @Keyhan Sir Basics a complex word.. I know the Concept hoe every Layout works..

Comment: ok, I wanted to know that exactly what you mean of "the same layout design as" expression. For example You want to know how dialogs can be transparent an no titlebar, or your purpose is about how the elements are beside eachother. I just wanted to know "exactly" what you mean :)

Comment: @KeyhanAsghari Sir If see the link that i have posted you'll know what i want to do.. :)

Comment: Sir if you sir the link that i have posted.. You'll know what i want to make :)

Comment: I saw, but I can't know your purpose exactly, so so sorry :(

Comment: One thing that might help you and you might be already know is there are some tools that you can extract an apk file. Using them you can get exactly what code is behind this app.

Answer (score 0):

you can make this using custom dialog for more help go to [custom dialog example](http://developer-dot-android.blogspot.com/2012/03/custom-dialog-in-activity.html)

or According too your requirement

this is your main XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mainLayout" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>
```

and java file is

```
package com.chirag;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;


public class TestActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(TestActivity.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
            //there are a lot of settings, for dialog, check them all out!


            //now that the dialog is set up, it's time to show it    
            dialog.show();
   }
}
```

I hope now its work for you...

Comment: Sir If you the link that i Have Posted.. The Layout beneath Does not have a button or something.. I want to show both tha layouts at the beginning when the app starts...

Comment: means you want that dialog at when your application starts so for that you have to set background image to root layout and show this dialog in onCreate() method directly .... because without Activity you can't show your dialog....I edited My answer according to your requirement ...